# Using findall and clickall without getting an error if image doesn't exit

Tags: python, jython, sikuli

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The code works great as long as there is an image displayed for the `findall`, but if `x` doesn't appear, then I get an error:

`[error] FindFailed ( can not find P(1474201252795.png) S: 0.99 in R[0,0 1920x1080]@S(0) )`

Not quite sure how to fix this.

```
running = True

def runHotkey(event):
    global running
    running = False

Env.addHotkey(Key.F1, KeyModifier.CTRL, runHotkey)

while exists("1474199877323.png")and running:

    click("1474138615993.png")
    click("1474138629993.png")
    wait(5)
    if exists("1474201633804.png"):
        for x in findAll(Pattern("1474201252795.png").exact()):
          click(x)
          click("1474201809505.png")       
    else:
        click("1474201689791.png")
    wait(5)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per documentation `findAll` throws an Exception on failed search. ([docs](https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli/blob/develop/sikuli-script/src/main/java/org/sikuli/script/Region.java#L434)). Try to use `hasNext()` method along with context manager, e.g.

```
with findAll(Pattern(...)) as mm:
    while mm.hasNext():
        x = mm.next()
        // process x
```

Answer (score -1):

Use try/catch

```
private boolean exists(Pattern img, int sec) {
        try {
            window.wait(img, sec);
            return true;
        } catch (FindFailed exception) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to avoid the error is to check if the image exist before using findAll:

```
if exists("image_in_findAll.png"):
    for x in findAll("image.png"):
        ...
```